# ORA-00903: invalid table name when executing UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I get an error

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

when trying to execute an `UPDATE` statement on a table created from the standard `EMP_DEPT` reason. What am I doing wrong? I cannot spot any errors in my statements.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP2
AS SELECT empno "ID", ename "FIRST_NAME", deptno "DEPT_ID", sal "SALARY"
FROM emp;

UPDATE TABLE EMP2
SET ID = (SELECT ID
        FROM EMP2
        WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'CLARK')
WHERE Salary <= (SELECT Salary
FROM EMP2
WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'MARTIN');
```

Comment: UPDATE TABLE EMP2 should be UPDATE EMP2

Answer (score 1):

Use as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5)

```
UPDATE   EMP2 ...
```

instead of

```
UPDATE TABLE EMP2 ...
```